# ZF2 is there a way to access a css file inside a module?

Tags: zend-framework2

[image]

I am getting a 404 error when checking if it is accessible via browser

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager is a module specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `public` folder for this.

Add all public files (files you want to access from your client) to the public folder.

[image]